# How to add spacing between two words using NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uitextview, nsattributedstring

Say I have a sentence rendered `That looks like this`.

If I wanted there to be more space on either said of `like`, how would I do that? So it would effectively look like `That looks   like   this.`

Injecting spaces won't work.

Comment: use "\t" tab in string like "That looks\t like this"

Comment: Why won't adding spaces work? Use non-break spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\u{2000}` in swift. (Probably `\u2000` in Objective-C.)

Comment: In the answer above, the spaces are wide ones, you can copy and paste them. (Not in this comment, here they are normal spaces.)

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in a somehow different way. As I need to add space of specific width. Please check the code below.

```
let image5Attachment = NSTextAttachment()
image5Attachment.image = UIImage(named: "")
image5Attachment.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: -5, width: 12, height: 0.0001)
// wrap the attachment in its own attributed string so we can append it
let imageSpaceHorizontal = NSAttributedString(attachment: image5Attachment)
```

I gave very little height, As I need horizontal Space and don't want any placeholder image. you can use it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this

**1. Option**

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"That looks %4s this",[@"like" UTF8String]];
```

**%@** formatter doesn't add spaces to adjust field width. So I use UTF8String with %s specifier to adjust width.

Width specifies a minimum number of characters to output, and it is typically used to pad fixed-width fields in tabulated output

**2nd Option**

Add tab space in string

```
NSString *string = @"That looks \t like this";
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Why is option 1 so convoluted? Just add spaces before and after the word.

Comment: Yes, add normal spaces it will work but don't know why it is not working for him.

Comment: So then how does your option 1 "solution" solve the problem? Your code simply gives the exact same string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSString *string = @"That looks \u00a0 \u00a0 like this";
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this with attributes, set the font in the ranges where the spaces are to a font bigger than the rest of the string.  (substantially bigger for a proportional font)

```
NSString *string = @"That looks like this";
NSMutableAttributedString *attrString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];

[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                   value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:50.0] // big
                   range:NSMakeRange(4, 1)];
[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                   value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:50.0]
                   range:NSMakeRange(10, 1)];

// present it somewhere where attributes are rendered
self.textView.attributedText = attrString;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can this too

```
[yourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"like" withString:@" like "];
```